# Laplace expansion for determinants with Octave

Tags: recursion, matrix, octave

I'm trying to calculate the determinant of a matrix using [Laplace expansion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion) in Octave. I use two functions:

- `submatrix`, gets [submatrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)) given matrix and indices:

  ```
  function A = submatrix(A, i, j)
     A(i,:) = [];
     A(:,j) = [];
  endfunction
  ```
- `determinant`, for recursively calculating the determinant:

  ```
  function d = determinant(A) 
      [m,n] = size(A);

      if m == 2
          # Base case are 2x2 matrices
          d = A(1,1)*A(2,2) - A(1,2)*A(2,1);
      else
          d = 0;
          for j = 1:n
              d = d + (-1).^(1+j)*determinant(submatrix(A,1,j));
          endfor
      endif
  endfunction
  ```

The function works correctly with 3 by 3 matrices, yet it always returns 0 (or -0) for bigger matrices (4 by 4 and bigger).

**Question:** Why does `determinant` returns 0 for matrices bigger than 3 by 3?

Comment: This looks like homework. You have to debug it yourself. Try to remove some `;` to see intermediate results, or include the `keyboard`instruction.

Comment: @ederag: I already tried debugging but got no useful information. The only result I got was that there is a point from which `d` stays 0, which I can't find any explanation. Also, I didn't tag it as `homework` because of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated